# Setting dynamic database in config during Login - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, dynamic

I'm trying to change the database connection on login based on the user's company.

Here my user has a company and its DB is **companyA**.

Below is my LoginController where I changed the connection:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user)
{
    \Config::set('database.connections.dynamicdb', array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql', 
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  =>  $user->company,
        'username'  =>  'root',
        'password'  =>  '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'strict'    => false,
        'options'   => [                                
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
        ]
    ));

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

So based on `user->company` which is already defined in users table, the database name is changed.

But somehow it doesn't work. The error shown is

> No database selected.

I tried below code to check if the values are set during login.

```
return \Config::get('database.connections.dynamicdb');
```

It showed all values set to my requirements. But when I check after login and reaching /home, the value of database in config is null.

So what all changes should I do. Is my technique right? Or is there any other solution for this.

In my Stock Model i have added the below lines:

```
protected $table = 'stocks';  
protected $connection = 'dynamicdb';
```

And the query I'm running is just a get all query:

```
 Stock::orderBy('tag_no','asc')->get()
```

Can anyone please tell me why this happens? What should i do?

Comment: This link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041893/laravel-change-database-connection-run-time

Comment: Yeah but its still not working

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280189/laravel-change-database-parameters-at-run-time

Comment: As @ZaquPL explains in his answer, whatever config you set is only going to be good for the current request, ie the request where the user logs in and `authenticated()` is called. As soon as your `redirect()` happens at the end of that method, that generates a new request, and the default config is loaded again.

Comment: you want use multi databases same connection ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**All requests are stateless** so current request doesn't know that you set new config value in previous request.

You should call `Config::set(...)` every time when you want to use dynamic database and set database name getting this value from `User` instance.

Setting above should be done using [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware) and [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers).

Create new middleware and register it for `web` middleware group (You may do this using the $middlewareGroups property of your HTTP kernel):

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        //...
        \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware::class,
    ],
    //...
];
```

Then:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class YourMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $database_name = Auth::user()->company;

            // Set your config here using $user->company
            // ...
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

If you must to set this value once (during authentication), you should combine above code and sessions to store this information between requests:

```
session(['db_name' => $dbname]); // Set db_name and store it

$db_name = session('db_name'); // Get db_name from session
```

Read more about HTTP Sessions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#retrieving-data

Comment: Good answer, however I have 1 addition. In order to ensure that the right database is used also call `DB::reconnect();`

Answer (score 0):

First you need create new default db for connection and add to  database.php like normal connection

```
    'dynamicdb' => [
        'driver'      => 'mysql',
        'host'        => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'        => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database'    => 'default',
        //others
    ],
```

next overriding model methods in Stock

```
   protected $table = 'stocks';  
   protected $connection = 'dynamicdb';

 /**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTable()
{
    $table = parent::getTable();
    $database = config('database.connections.dynamicdb.database');
    return starts_with($table, $database)
        ? $table
        : $database . '.' . parent::getTable();
}

/**
 * Set the table associated with the model.
 *
 * @param  string $table
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTable($table)
{
    $database = config('database.connections.dynamicdb.database');
    $this->table = starts_with($table, $database)
        ? $table
        : $database . '.' . $table;

    return $this;
}
```

Usage : `\Config::set('database.connections.dynamicdb.database',$user->company);` or you can create helper for it 
Don't forget this method work only one connection and connected user have access all databases

Answer (score 0):

Add Multiple DB in **.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

ALT_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
ALT_DB_PORT=3306
ALT_DB_DATABASE=database2
ALT_DB_USERNAME=root
ALT_DB_PASSWORD=
```

Edit **config/database.php**

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        ......
    ],

    'alt_mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('ALT_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('ALT_DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('ALT_DB_DATABASE', 'vibecloud'),
        ...
    ],
```

If Whole model used for ALT_MYSQL then

```
protected $connection = 'alt_mysql';
```

ELSE

```
protected function stock_info() {
  return \DB::connection('alt_mysql')->select('*')->from('stocks')->get();
}
```

Comment: For every call we might have to call this. So this is one solution but not the prefect one.